# Shisha Ve'esrim Umatayim - mi yodeya?

Tags: mi-yodeya-series, number

### Who knows two hundred twenty-six?

*Please cite/link your sources, if possible. At some point at least twenty-four hours from now, I will:*

- *Upvote all interesting answers.*
- *Accept the best answer.*
- *Go on to the next number.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Rambam Hilchos Sefer Torah 9:10](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/i/2309.htm) says that the Sefer Torah the Rambam wrote for himself had 226 Dafim.

Answer (score 1):

צפון = 226

צפון is one the Simanim of the Seder. It is also the Hebrew word for North.

Comment: Ironically also the word "וְיִרְדּוּ֩" in Bereshis 1:26 ("and" subdue/descend)